# Encoding russian text on kinoposik

Tags: c#, request, httpwebrequest, httprequest

I want to parse a film page on kinopoisk, but in a response russian text looks like "Р•СЃР»Рё РІР°Рј РїРѕРЅСЂР°РІРёР»СЃСЏ СЌС‚РѕС". I tried different encodings, but couldn't resolve the problem.

```
        int y = 2008;
        string n = "Hancock";

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)
            WebRequest.Create($@"http://www.kinopoisk.ru/s/type/film/find/{n}/m_act%5Byear%5D/{y}/");

        req.Method = "GET";
        req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36";
        req.Accept = @"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,";
        req.KeepAlive = true;

        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251")))
        {
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\MyTest.html", reader.ReadToEnd());
        }
```

Comment: Add encoding to WriteAllText : File.WriteAllText(@"C:\test\MyTest.html", reader.ReadToEnd(), Encoding.GetEncoding("windows-1251"));

Comment: See this http://i.piccy.info/i7/555e1b87052311d4f61f62f9ba92537e/4-47-589/17169915/Pamiatka_po_kodyrovkam_1200.jpg

Comment: This should really be tagged with "character-encoding".